# VLC plugin does not stream

Tags: firefox, vlc-media-player

I have

```
Firefox 22
VLC media player 2.0.7
VLC Mozilla Web Plugin 2.0.6
```

However if I click a link to a video, it still attempts to download it instead of streaming it. It only streams it if I open VLC and

<kbd>Media</kbd> <kbd>Open Network Stream</kbd>

It appears this is a problem for files with MIME type

```
application/octet-stream
video/quicktime
```

Comment: What does it say in Firefox button -> Options -> Applications -> <video file type>?

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar `Use VLC Web Plugin (in Firefox)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this problem by installing Launchy

[`addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/launchy`](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/launchy)